# Kivy: Why are children not visible in __init__?

Tags: python, kivy, children, init

I have a simple demonstration app here, called "question".  It contains one label and two buttons.  The text on the label has to change depending on which button I press.  Please have a look:

[image]

Not much to it, really.

That works with the code below:

`question.kv`:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<NormalKey>:

<Keyboard>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        NormalKey:
            id:          key_A
            text:       "A"
            on_release:  root.key_released(self.text)

        NormalKey:
            id:          key_B        
            text:       "B"
            on_release: root.key_released(self.text)

<MainPanel>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            id:    label_1
            text: "This text will change"

        Keyboard:
            linked_label: label_1
```

and `question.py`:

```
from kivy.app           import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button    import Button
from kivy.uix.label     import Label    

class NormalKey(Button):
    def __init__( self, **kwargs ):
        super(NormalKey, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Keyboard(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Keyboard, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        print self           # -->
        print self.children  # --> DOES NOT PRINT CHILDREN HERE
        print self.ids       # -->  

    def key_released(self, value):
        self.linked_label.text = value    

        print self           # -->
        print self.ids       # --> BUT PRINTS CHILDREN HERE 
        print self.children  # --> 


class MainPanel(BoxLayout):
    pass

class QuestionApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainPanel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QuestionApp().run()
```

As you can see, I have class `NormalKey`, derived from `Button`, and I have `Keyboard`, derived from `BoxLayout`.

`Keyboard` has two children in it, two `NormalKey`s, hence two children.  However, in `__init__`, `Keyboard` does not seem to be aware of them, yet in another function, `key_released` in above example, children are clearly present :-(

Can anyone explain me why children are not visible in `__init__`, and if there is a way to somehow see them, access them?

Maybe the children are not accessible because the `Keyboard` is being built.  If that is the case, can I somehow create a function which would be called just after the widget is build?

Answer (score 2):

Children aren't present in the `Keyboard` class `__init__` method becasue this method only creates a base of the widget, which will be later populated by its parent calling its `add_widget` method. You can overwrite this method to obserwe as new children are added:

```
class Keyboard(BoxLayout):
    def add_widget(self, widget, *args):
        super(Keyboard, self).add_widget(widget, *args)
        print(widget)
```

Another thing you can do is observing `children` property - method `on_children` will be called every time a new children is added, bringing updated version of a list:

```
class Keyboard(BoxLayout):
    def on_children(self, obj, children):
        print(children)
```

Finally, if you wan to have method called after entire `Keyboard` object is created, you can bind that object to an `ObjectProperty` and observe it in its parent class:

```
Builder.load_string("""

# ...

<MainPanel>:
    keyboard: keyboard

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            id:    label_1
            text: "This text will change"

        Keyboard:
            linked_label: label_1
            id: keyboard
""")

class MainPanel(BoxLayout):
    keyboard = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_keyboard(self, panel, keyboard):
        print(keyboard)
        print(list(keyboard.ids))
        print(keyboard.children)
```

All these method will show that `Keyboard` object has only one child, `BoxLayout`, because it's in fact the only child of that object:

```
<Keyboard>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
```

You doesn't chave to add `BoxLayout` inside the `Keyboard` object because this object is already a `BoxLayout` itself (as the descendant of this class). You basically have a `BoxLayout` inside a `BoxLayout`. I believe that this is what you meant:

```
<Keyboard>:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    NormalKey:
        id:          key_A
        text:       "A"
        on_release:  root.key_released(self.text)

    NormalKey:
        id:          key_B        
        text:       "B"
        on_release: root.key_released(self.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nykakin.  It is late with me now, but will go through your answers tomorrow.